# Historical sources on Bar Kochba?

Tags: history, bar-kochba

Does anyone know any books or articles I can read to learn more about Bar Kohkba?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Joe and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Not all questions are in scope, and this one might get closed for being about individual Jews while this site is focused on Judaism. If that is the case, please don't be upset and come back to learn with us

Comment: Perhaps edit your connection with this guy and mi yodeyas guidelines

Comment: @Joe Bernstein Consult _Jewish Encyclopedia_ online. Also _Encyclopaedia Brittanica_ , which mentions the recent discovery of letters he wrote to his lieutenants.

Answer (score 1):

A classic book on Bar Kochba is from famous Israeli archeologist [Yigael Yadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yigael_Yadin):

[Bar-Kokhba; the rediscovery of the legendary hero of the last Jewish revolt against Imperial Rome](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0297003453)

but I also know of [The Bar Kokhba War AD 132–135](https://smile.amazon.com/Bar-Kokhba-War-AD-132-135/dp/1472817982/ref=sr_1_4?keywords=Bar%20Kochba&qid=1549810771&s=gateway&sr=8-4).

Note Wiki's entry on [Bar Kochba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_bar_Kokhba#In_popular_culture) and [his revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_Kokhba_revolt#Sources) mention other relevant works.

Answer (score 1):

Talmud Yerushalmi , Taanit 4:5 (24a) and Midrash Rabba (Lamentations Rabba 2:5).

A link that I found https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Joseph_Geiger/publication/310512261_The_Bar-Kokhba_revolt_The_Greek_point_of_view/links/5c0fc0fba6fdcc494fec0241/The-Bar-Kokhba-revolt-The-Greek-point-of-view.pdf?origin=publication_detail.